# How to authenticate to Azurite using pyspark?

Tags: docker, pyspark, azurite

I am building an application using two docker containers in the same network:

- mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
- jupyter/pyspark-notebook

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  azurite:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite:latest
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "10001:10001"
      - "10002:10002"
    volumes:
      - azurite_volume:/data
  
  pyspark:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
    ports:
      - 10003:8888
    user: root
    working_dir: /home/${NB_USER}
    environment:
      - NB_USER=${NB_USER}
      - CHOWN_HOME=yes
      - GRANT_SUDO=yes
    command: start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password="" --NotebookApp.token=""
    volumes:
      - /my/local/folder:/home/${NB_USER}/work

volumes:
  azurite_volume:
    driver: local
```

from the jupyter notebook I am trying to connect to and read data from azurite. Here is my code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('test') \
    .config(
        'fs.azure.account.key.devstoreaccount1.blob.core.windows.net',
        'Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==') \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json('wasb://my-container@devstoreaccount1/path/to/file.json')
```

However, this code returns an error:

```sh
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Unable to access container bronze in account devstoreaccount1 using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them  in the configuration.
```

The container in azurite has already been set to "public" although it wouldn`t be necessary because I am providing the credential in the spark config. Even though, the error tells me that I am using anonymous credentials...

I am probably setting the credentials wrongly but I couldn't find anywhere how to set them properly.

How can I set up the credentials to be able to read from azurite using pyspark?

Comment: any updates on this issue? im facing the same thing